# How to add panel in content page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to find a panel in content page and need to add a drop downlist on that panel.I have searched but i got only for adding controls to master page.Below is my code,
Note:I have to add control from that page itself not from master page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Salesorder.aspx.cs" Inherits="Salesorder" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
  <div class="row">
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"> 
</asp:Panel>             
        </div>
</asp:Content>
```

I need to add another panel to Panel1 from codebehind.

```
    protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          //Create a Dynamic Panel
          Panel pnlDropDownList; 
          pnlDropDownList = new Panel();
          pnlDropDownList.ID = "pnlDropDownList";
          pnlDropDownList.BorderWidth = 1;
          pnlDropDownList.Width = 300;
          ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Page.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
          Panel panel = (Panel)cph.FindControl("Panel1");
          cph.Controls.Add(pnlDropDownList);
       }
```

Comment: Can you show us your C# code you are trying to work on?

Comment: protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create a Dynamic Panel
        Panel pnlDropDownList; pnlDropDownList = new Panel();
        pnlDropDownList.ID = "pnlDropDownList";
        pnlDropDownList.BorderWidth = 1;
        pnlDropDownList.Width = 300;
        ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Page.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
          Panel panel = (Panel)cph.FindControl("Panel1");
          cph.Controls.Add(pnlDropDownList);}

Comment: I have put a code @Codeek

Comment: don't add pnlDropDownList in "cph". add it in "panel". btw, why are you adding dropdownlist in separate panel?

Comment: why you write this line? `Panel panel = (Panel)cph.FindControl("Panel1");`

Comment: @Codeek,I am new to dotnet,Could you please kindly help me to solve the issue by posting full code

Comment: @MirzaDanishBaig, To find that control and add a dynamic panel to that panel1

Comment: @Priya Are you getting any error??

Comment: Why are you adding a Panel to that already existing Panel if you want to add a Drop-down List ?

Comment: @Priya so add this dynamically generated panel  to `Panel1` no need to first find cph. just do this `panel.Controls.Add(pnlDropDownList);'

Comment: @NagarajS,Everytime its showing error like Object reference not set to an instance of an object...Cph and panel1 returning null when using find control

Comment: @Priya, No, I am sorry bt I won't do that. bt you can refer http://www.aspsnippets.com/Red/Articles/Creating-Dynamic-DropDownList-Controls-in-ASP.Net.aspx. Note : Simply create a dropdownlist control instance and add it to Panel1 with Panel1.Controls.Add(dropdownlistInstance)

Comment: @HarveySpecter,Because dynamic controls are adding somewhere on the page,to avoid that i have placed a panel already,and then im adding dynamic controls

Comment: try to find ContentPlaceHolder by id like this `ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Page.FindControl("Content2");`

Comment: @MirzaDanishBaig,no luck.....!.Showing same error.

Comment: please any one help me

Comment: please see answer, i put the answer.

Comment: @Priya [Hope this link will help you](http://forums.asp.net/t/1189482.aspx?Dynamically+Adding+Controls+in+Content+which+is+using+MasterPage)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to find your control in Master instead of Page.

Like below.

```
ContentPlaceHolder cph = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");
```

this should work.

Comment: i have tried that too its working,but control name is going too long..then selectedindex propery of dropdownlist not triggeing.

Comment: which control, dropdownlist? or control name or id?

Comment: Dropdownlist control name

Comment: so what you need to do with dropdownlost, and it is dynamically generated na?

Answer (score 0):

Add a PlaceHolder control in the panel you want the new DropDownList panel to be added in the aspx page

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"> 
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeholder1" runat="server"></PlaceHolder>
</asp:Panel>
```

In the code behind, to add the control to the page use:

```
placeholder1.Controls.add(pnlDropDownList);
```

Answer (score -3):

I can't understand why don't you add controls like this

```
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

Comment: OP is not like to add dropdownlist, read the question carefully.

Comment: @ruken aslan,I have to create a dropdown list whenever the button is getting clicked,according to the user need.

Comment: I am sorry about my answer. I had better read questions carrefully @priya

Comment: @DenishParvadia - O Deni.

Comment: @Codeek,Actually i took the code from that site only.its working fine with normal page not with master and content page.PLz anyone help me

Comment: why are you so unpolite?